# Delphi XE & OmniXML: Using SelectNode()?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe, omnixml

I've got the following XML snippet as part of a larger XML file that I'm processing using the latest OmniXML snapshot:

```
<OrderRequestHeader>
<!-- snipped XML bits here -->
<ShipTo>                                                        
    <Address addressID="">                                      
        <Name xml:lang="en">SOME COMPANY</Name>        
        <PostalAddress name="default">                          
            <DeliverTo>John Doe</DeliverTo>                  
            <Street>123 Any St</Street>                  
            <City>Nowhere</City>                              
            <State>AK</State>                                   
            <PostalCode>99999</PostalCode>                      
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
        </PostalAddress>                                        
        <Email/>                                                
        <Phone>                                                 
            <TelephoneNumber>                                   
                <CountryCode isoCountryCode=""/>                
                <AreaOrCityCode/>                               
                <Number></Number>                               
            </TelephoneNumber>                                  
        </Phone>                                                
    </Address>                                                  
</ShipTo>
<!-- more XML stuff follows -->
</OrderRequestHeader>
```

I've currently got a variable pointing to the `<ShipTo>` node, and want to select the contents of the `<Name>` node.  I'm using the following code, but `Node2` is coming up `Nil`...

```
procedure ProcessXML;
var
    Node1, Node2: IXMLNode;

begin
    Node1 := FindNode(OrderHeader, 'ShipTo');
    // the above is working.  Node points to the <ShipTo> node
    Node2 := SelectNode(Node1, 'Name');
    // the above line doesn't work.  Node2 is Nil
end;
```

Why is `Node2` `Nil`?  According to the help in `OmniXMLUtils.pas`, `SelectNode` will select a single node possibly more than one level below.  There's definitely a `<Name>` node.  Even trying to find the node via `XPathSelect(Node1, 'Name');` returns an empty list.  Am I using OmniXML wrong somehow?  Is it possible to get to the `<Name>` node without first selecting the `<Address>` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectNode` works fine, if you put double-slash characters in front:

```
var
  FXMLDocument: IXMLDocument;

// Somewhere along the line
  FXMLDocument := CreateXMLDocument
  XMLLoadFromFile(FXMLDocument, 'WhateverFile.xml');
  // or XMLLoadFromAnsiString(FXMLDocument, SomeStringVar);


var
  QryNode, Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  QryNode := FXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
  Node := SelectNode(QryNode, 'ShipTo');
  if Assigned(Node) then
  begin
    QryNode := SelectNode(Node, '//Name');
    if Assigned(QryNode) then
      ShowMessage('ShipTo Name is ' + QryNode.FirstChild.Text)
    else
      ShowMessage('Name not found');
  end;
end;
```

If you prefer, XPath works fine as well:

```
implementation

var
  FXMLDocument: IXMLDocument;

// Somewhere along the line
  FXMLDocument := CreateXMLDocument
  XMLLoadFromFile(FXMLDocument, 'WhateverFile.xml');
  // or XMLLoadFromAnsiString(FXMLDocument, SomeStringVar);

function GetShipTo: string;
var
  QryNode: IXMLNode;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  NodeList: IXMLNodeList;
begin
  Result := '';
  QryNode := FXMLDocument.DocumentElement;  

  // The following also work:
  // '//Address/Name'
  // '//Name'
  NodeList := XPathSelect(QryNode, '//ShipTo/Address/Name');
  if NodeList.Length > 0 then
    QryNode := NodeList.Item[0]
  else
    QryNode := nil;
  if Assigned(QryNode) then
    Result := QryNode.FirstChild.Text; // Now has 'SOME COMPANY'
end;
```

Comment: I don't really want to go all the way up to the document level though, I want to dive down in under the node I already have.

Comment: @afrazier: I've updated my answer to show you how to do it with `SelectNode` from the node you're at (using something like what your original code reflected).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was doing wrong: I have to specify the entire relative path, not just the name of the grandchild node I want.

From my `ProcessXML` example above, I have to fill in `Node2` like so:

```
Node2 := SelectNode(Node, 'Address/Name');
```

Using XPath, I'd have to find it via `XPathSelect(Node, 'Address/Name');`