# omni xml , is there a simple current example for reading xml file?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2009, omnixml

Looking for readable example use of Omni Xml package.

the documentation now is 2 examples, for loading and writing, nothing about reading, nor iterating.

could you provide a simple reading Xml ,example of one repeatable property

such as

```
<root>
<value p1=1></value>
<value p1=2 p2='32432'/>
<value p1=3 p3='fdsf'><other></other></value>
</root>
```

how to iterate over all the values and get the p1 property.

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513917/delphi-xe-omnixml-using-selectnode). It shows how to access child nodes. Does it help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uses
  OmniXML,
  OmniXMLUtils;

var
  node : IXMLNode;
  other: IXMLNode;
  xml  : IXMLDocument;
begin
  xml := CreateXMLDoc;
  if XMLLoadFromFile(xml, 'fname.xml') then begin // 3 more notes
    for node in XMLEnumNodes(xml,'/root/value') do begin
      Writeln(GetNodeAttrStr(node, 'p1', ''), ';', GetNodeAttrStr(node, 'p2', ''), ';', 
        GetNodeAttrStr(node, 'p3', ''));
      other := SelectNode(node, 'other');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Warning: Untested, written in browser.

Comment: XMLEnumNodes, is overloaded with 3 functions, for enumaration by node by xml or by nodelist. very useful for "for".